# HTML5 pattern for validating IP with mask

Tags: regex, html, ip

I'm trying to create a HTML5 pattern for input text with and IP address and mask together, like this:

10.120.15.30/28 or 172.181.30.0/24

I found one html5 pattern at http://html5pattern.com/Miscs but is only for IPv4 without mask

```
((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}$
```

I tried add before

```
    (\/).((([0-2])|(0-9))|(3[1-2]))
```

but is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: As webpage to test the pattern there is http://html5pattern.com/Make_Your_Own, is where i'm testing the patterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}/(?:\d|[12]\d|3[01])$
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/oH0bU6/5)

I simply added `/(?:\d|[12]\d|3[01])`to the pattern you provided:

```
/          // match a slash
(?:        // then match either one of
    \d     // a single digit
|
    [12]\d // any number from 10 to 29
|
    3[01]  // 30 or 31
)
```

Comment: Perfect! I was only using html5patterns, but with regex that works like a charm. Thank you! :)

Comment: Aren't the prefixes only 24-31 as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnet_and_host_counts, i.e. `(/(2[4-9]|3[01]))?`

Comment: I think the first sollution was the correct, as I could remark a single host as xx.xx.xx.xx/32